# Deselecting the TextView field after clicking an area outside TextView

Tags: java, android

The following code marks the given TextView field, and then after pressing the button I delete TextView and all the information that was in it. I would like to add, that if I press the TextView field and the field is marked, then after pressing the area outside the TextView field I would like the TextView field to be unchecked. How can I achieve this effect?

```
breakfastListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                itemSelectedbreakfast = i;
                isSelectedbreakfast = true;
                breakfastListView.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
            }
        });



button_removeProductBreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

//code

            }
        });
```

EDIT:

This is my layout, let's say I added some product to the meal and then I would like to remove it from the meal I added it to. So I mark the product that is placed on the ListView and the method, setOnItemClickListener, will be called, which sets the variables:

```
itemSelectedbreakfast = i; 
isSelectedbreakfast = true;
```

This setting of variables is used in removing the product after pressing the RemoveProduct button. To the merits, if pressed once in a product on the list in a given meal, it is always selected, and the variables are set in the same way as in the setOnItemClickListener method, but I would like the product field to be unchecked after pressing any area outside the field of the product and variables have been set to:

```
itemSelectedbreakfast = 0; 
isSelectedbreakfast = false;
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the area outside the TextView field"?

Comment: So your list item is a textview? Is clicking on outside means clicking on another listitem(i.e textview)? These problems should be cleared before answering. You should add the layout file. The context you've provided is not sufficient for someone to provide a solution.

Comment: I have edited my post and added some additional information and layout. I would just like to unselect the product on the list by pressing any field other than the product field that is selected.